# Copy url from Action.OpenUrl

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I am using this https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Action.OpenUrl.html as below:

```
    "actions": [
    {
        "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
        "title": "View details",
        "url": "${ViewDetailsUrl}"
    }
    ]
```

And rendering it on Microsoft Teams in a channel.
[View details button on adaptive card in Teams channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahcCi.png)

Now, when I right click on this button and use copy option, the link to channel message gets copied.
How do I make sure that the link which opens when we click on the button gets copied instead?

Is there any mechanism for the same?

How do I copy the url specified in "Action.OpenUrl" entity?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be feasible. To achieve your requirements, we recommend you give your feedback in [Teams Feedback Portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472)

Comment: Does that mean this functionality is not yet available and I need to raise feature request?

Comment: Yes, please raise the feature request.